# How to persist OffsetTime and OffsetDateTime with JPA and Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, java-8, hibernate-mapping, java-time

How can I persist Java 8 `OffsetTime` and `OffsetDateTime` with Hibernate as proper SQL types (`TIME_WITH_TIMEZONE` and `TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE`)?

I found a solution for `LocalTime` and `LocalDateTime` using `EnhancedUserType`s in [a blog](http://blog.progs.be/550/java-time-hibernate).

How would the user types be for *offset* data?

Comment: See [HHH-8844](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8844) (Hibernate bug database) - apparently this is still not a standard feature in Hibernate. (The comments on that issue contain a link to the blog you already found...).

Answer (score 6):

Hibernate ORM 5.3 implements the JPA 2.2 standard.

---

### Supported types from the [Java 8 Date and Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)

The [**JPA 2.2**](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_2-mrel-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf?AuthParam=1649396204_29fc9e061911833a8744179a351d1a54) specification says that the following Java 8 types are supported:

- `java.time.LocalDate`
- `java.time.LocalTime`
- `java.time.LocalDateTime`
- `java.time.OffsetTime`
- `java.time.OffsetDateTime`

Hibernate ORM supports all these types, and even more:

- `java.time.ZonedDateTime`
- `java.time.Duration`

---

## Entity mapping

Assuming you have the following entity:

```java
@Entity(name = "DateTimeEntity")
public static class DateTimeEntity {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(name = "duration_value")
    private Duration duration = Duration.of( 20, ChronoUnit.DAYS );
    
    @Column(name = "instant_value")
    private Instant instant = Instant.now();
    
    @Column(name = "local_date")
    private LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
    
    @Column(name = "local_date_time")
    private LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    
    @Column(name = "local_time")
    private LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.now();
    
    @Column(name = "offset_date_time")
    private OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.now();
    
    @Column(name = "offset_time")
    private OffsetTime offsetTime = OffsetTime.now();
    
    @Column(name = "zoned_date_time")
    private ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now();
    
    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

The `DateTimeEntity` will have an associated database table that looks as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE DateTimeEntity (
    id                  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    duration_value      BIGINT,
    instant_value       TIMESTAMP,
    local_date          DATE,
    local_date_time     TIMESTAMP,
    local_time          TIME,
    offset_date_time    TIMESTAMP,
    offset_time         TIME,
    zoned_date_time     TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

---

*Source*: [Mapping Java 8 Date/Time entity attributes with Hibernate](http://in.relation.to/2018/02/20/java8-date-time-mapping/)

Answer (score 4):

Since version 2.2, JPA offers support for mapping Java 8 Date/Time API, like `LocalDateTime`, `LocalTime`, `LocalDateTimeTime`, `OffsetDateTime` or `OffsetTime`.

Also, even with JPA 2.1, Hibernate 5.2 supports all Java 8 Date/Time API by default.

In Hibernate 5.1 and 5.0, you have to add the `hibernate-java8` Maven dependency.

So, let's assume we have the following `Notification` entity:

```
@Entity(name = "Notification")
@Table(name = "notification")
public class Notification {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "created_on")
    private OffsetDateTime createdOn;

    @Column(name = "notify_on")
    private OffsetTime clockAlarm;

    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

Notice that the `createdOn` attribute is a `OffsetDateTime` Java object and the `clockAlarm` is of the `OffsetTime` type.

When persisting the `Notification`:

```
ZoneOffset zoneOffset = ZoneOffset.systemDefault().getRules()
    .getOffset(LocalDateTime.now());

Notification notification = new Notification()
    .setId(1L)
    .setCreatedOn(
        LocalDateTime.of(
            2020, 5, 1,
            12, 30, 0
        ).atOffset(zoneOffset)
    ).setClockAlarm(
        OffsetTime.of(7, 30, 0, 0, zoneOffset)
    );

entityManager.persist(notification);
```

Hibernate generates the proper SQL INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO notification (
    notify_on, 
    created_on, 
    id
) 
VALUES (
    '07:30:00', 
    '2020-05-01 12:30:00.0', 
    1
)
```

When fetching the `Notification` entity, we can see that the `OffsetDateTime` and `OffsetTime`
are properly fetched from the database:

```
Notification notification = entityManager.find(
    Notification.class, 1L
);

assertEquals(
    LocalDateTime.of(
        2020, 5, 1,
        12, 30, 0
    ).atOffset(zoneOffset),
    notification.getCreatedOn()
);

assertEquals(
    OffsetTime.of(7, 30, 0, 0, zoneOffset),
    notification.getClockAlarm()
);
```