# Strange binding behavior of Hibernate when storing OffsetTime (JVM) into Time

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, timezone

I had an unexpected result when try to store with Hibernate (5.6.1) **OffsetTime** entity properties into Postgresql **Time with time zone** field.

For ex (if **current default** zone is **+02**):

```
| OffsetTime| Timez    |
| --------  | -------- |
| 00:00+01  | 00:00+02 |
| 00:00+02  | 00:00+02 |
| 00:00+03  | 00:00+02 |
```

**Original offset was lost and stored default instead.**

I researched two classes:

- org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.TimeTypeDescriptor

```java
final Time time = javaTypeDescriptor.unwrap( value, Time.class, options );
```

- org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.OffsetTimeJavaDescriptor

```java
if ( java.sql.Time.class.isAssignableFrom( type ) ) {
    return (X) java.sql.Time.valueOf( offsetTime.toLocalTime() );
}
```

I think, that I had some mistake in understanding this logic, but in another answers I saw recommendation: ([LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61525553/15103694))

```java
 ZoneOffset zoneOffset = ZoneOffset.systemDefault().getRules()
            .getOffset(LocalDateTime.now());
    
 Notification notification = new Notification()
   //...
 ).setClockAlarm(
      OffsetTime.of(7, 30, 0, 0, zoneOffset)
 );
```

**So, do I must to convert all OffsetTime values to *default time zone* so that it store correctly?**

Comment: [Don't use time with time zone](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_timetz)

Comment: I see, that using timestamp is also goes that way but by OffsetTimeJavaDescriptor (->ZonedDateTime->toLocalDateTime()).

Comment: That's a bug. I created https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15679 for this.

Comment: I can just repeat again what other wrote: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_timetz